# How to make this initialization legal in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'va seen an **excersise** in a book, but I cannot figure out the answer:

> Is the following code legal or not? If not, how might you make it
>   legal?
>
> `int null = 0, *p = null;`

Of course, the second one is not legal, you cannot convert int to int*.

The theme was in the section the `constexpr`.

**GUYS! This is just an exercise about pointers, consts, and constexprs! I think, you have to solve it without cast and nullptr.**

Comment: Don't the book have a section with answers? What does it say?

Comment: There is no answer in the book

Comment: I still fail to see how `consexpr` plays into this at all

Comment: The name of the section is: "Pointers and constexpr", this is why I think you have to solve it with const and/or with constexpr

Comment: What is `p`? I suggest you add `int *p;`, or something like that, to your question

Comment: @AaronMcDaid What? `p` is being declared in the same declaration as `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11, a null pointer constant was defined as

> an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero

(C++11 [conv.ptr] 4.10/1)

This means that adding `constexpr` to the declaration actually makes `null` a valid null pointer constant:

```
constexpr int null = 0, *p = null;
```

Note that this was considered a defect and changed in C++14, so that only an integer *literal* can be a null pointer constant:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal with value zero ...

(C++14 N4140 [conv.ptr] 4.10/1)

So, there is a way to make the initialisation legal using `constexpr` in C++11, but its existence was considered a standard defect and removed in C++14. The book is therefore teaching outdated information.

Note that because this is a defect, compilers have generally backported this behaviour to their C++11 mode as well (if they even implemented the original one in the first place).

Comment: Nice! But you'd be hard pressed to find a compiler that accepts this, even when specifying c++11.

Comment: @aaaaaaaa Cause, as Angew mentioned, it was only valid for C++11, ideone is C++14.

Comment: @GillBates, specifying c++11 doesn't help either http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb5c0f3603c928e0

Comment: @StoryTeller on a fully conformant compiler™ it would work :)

Comment: Is `null` a **prvalue** here?

Comment: @krzaq, I suppose I'd also need a unicorn at midnight!?

Comment: @Pixelchemist It undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion before being used.

Comment: @Angew: "its existence was considered a standard defect and removed in C++14" - thank you!

Comment: @krzaq As it was considered a defect in C++11, a conforming compiler may choose to apply the fix even in C++11 mode.

Comment: @Oktalist didn't know that. Thanks. So "on a fully conformant compiler™ it could work" is the proper line :)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer miss a very simple solution to make it legal: Make `null` a pointer:

```
int *null = 0, *p = null;
```

But as noted, the best solution is to not use the `null` variable at all, but to use the standard `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going for the smallest diff, you can choose

```
int null = 0, *p = nullptr;
                       ^^^
```

or

```
int null = 0, *p = {};
```

or

```
int null = 0, *p = 0;
```

The last example might be surprising to you, but the way it's defined (in C++14) requires in integer literal with value zero. Not an object with type `int`.

---

Alternatively, if you don't indent to zero-initialize `p`, you could initialize it with `null`'s address:

```
int null = 0, *p = &null;
```

Comment: Second one deletes 3 characters and changes one.  First one adds 3.  Clearly first is smallest.

Comment: @Yakk and hey, it's mentioned first :)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to make it legal, to name a few:

```
int null = 0, *p = 0;

int null = 0, *p = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is not legal:

```
int null = 0, *p = null;
```

As well as this:

```
int null = 0, *p = static_cast<int*>(null);
```

These compile, and are equivalent:

```
int null = 0, *p = (int*)null;
int null = 0, *p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(null);
```

But should be avoided, as explained [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast).

The C-style cast `(int*)null` can be considered as a bad practice in C++ (to be clear, this part is a matter of opinion), mainly because it's hard to spot in a code either with your own eyes (there is usually no syntax hightlighting for casts) or with a search/find command (how to separate the casts from the other type usage, e.g. variable declarations?).

`reinterpret_cast` is more visible, and can be searched easily, but is as permissive as the C-style cast, so it should be avoided unless you know exactly why you're using it.

Of course, a good initialization in C++11 would be:

```
int null = 0, *p = nullptr;
```

Comment: imho a "good" initialization would not use `null` as a variable name. It is not really a problem, but it just looks a bit weird

Comment: That's legal, and naming the variable in lowercase makes it clearly different from `NULL` when reading. I wouldn't call a variable `null` in my own code, except maybe in a well-defined context like for the `null` value in JSON, but again that's legal, so the usage is a matter of opinion :)

Comment: `NULL` was always discouraged in c++ code, as far as I can remember. `0` was the initializer of preference.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `reinterpret_cast<int*>` over the int in order to make this valid.

Comment: I'm neither upvoting nor downvoting, but as far as I can tell, at the point of `p`'s definition the code with this cast will be valid.