# Pointer to reference to const null value

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

This is the code:

```
const int   x = 0;
const int&  r = x;

const int*  p1 = x;  // Works (p1 = 0)
const int*  p2 = r;  // error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const int' to 'const int *'
```

Why is p1 set to the value of x, but p2 not?

Is it because p2 cannot guarantee that x is const just by looking at r?
Or is there anything else subtle about references that causes this error?

Comment: `cosnt int* p1 = x;` shouldn't even compile. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Your first try with the `p1` is not legal either. Both your pointer initializations are wrong.

Comment: VS 2015 with /W4, /sdl and /WX on.  It doesn't compile if x is non-const, but compiles with const.

Comment: Read the error message again. Especially what it tells you about the types. Are the types the same?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Looks like Visual C++. But the next questions would be: 1) Which version? 2) Which compiler flags? You can cripple *every* C++ compiler by specifiying the wrong flags, and default flags are normally always the wrong ones.

Comment: Did the compiler warn you about the first line? If not, try it on its own, without the second line.

Comment: @Rakete1111 well in c++03 it actually might be valid...

Comment: @lousybyte: When I try `cl /W4 /SDL stackoverflow.cpp` with Visual C++ 2015 and your code in stackoverflow.cpp wrapped in a main function, then I get `Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/SDL'` **and** `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const int' to 'const int *'`. Are you sure those are your only two flags? Why`/SDL`?

Comment: @W.F. I would have **never** expected that. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: These are all the compiler options shown from the VS project command line page:  `/MP /GS /GL /analyze- /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\Test.pch" `

Comment: If i do a `std::cout << p1;` I get `00000000`.

Comment: @lousybyte: It may be better to try such things on the command line without Visual Studio. You can just invoke the compiler with `cl` and experiment with its different flags freely.

Comment: @lousybyte: That being said, I'm a bit at a loss. I expected VC to generate an error for both lines, but it doesn't, even with `/Za`. GCC, in contrast, will behave as expected.

Comment: No warnings or errors whatsoever for p1 for me.   `>cl /EHsc Main.cpp  
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

Main.cpp  
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

/out:Main.exe  
Main.obj`

Comment: @lousybyte: Yeah, and that's strange. Looks like a bug, but I cannot find an open issue for it at MSDN.

Comment: You get an error if you remove the `const`. Looks like MSVC is doing the constant folding *first*, before determining the validity of the assignment, so it simply interprets the code as `const int*  p1 = 0;`, which is totally valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third line should provoke an error. It doesn't in VS2015, because of a bug in either the compiler or in the standard, depending on which standard is applied. Other compilers do emit error messages about this line.

Before C++11, any integral constant expression that evaluates to 0 is treated as a *null pointer constant*, so the first line is equivalent to `const int*  p1 = NULL;`, It *doesn't make p1 point to x*.

Since C++14 this is no longer the case. Roughly speaking, only literal zero and `nullptr` are valid null pointer constants.

In between, that is, in C++11, the standard actually permits constant expressions that evaluate to zero to be treated as null pointer constants. This is regarded as a defect in the standard. It was fixed in C++14. Some compilers (gcc, clang) choose to fix the defect right away and report an error even in C++11 mode. VS2015 does not.

The fourth line was never valid in any version of C++, because the type of `r` is a reference, not an integer.

Comment: I've not found any reference to this bug on the internet. Do you happen to know if there's an open issue for it, or any official information from MS (perhaps "won't fix")?

Comment: C++11 states that "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.". Apparently it was deemed a defect in the standard and has been changed in 14. A related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40787595/2456565

Answer (score -1):

Pointers represent the *address of* a value, so to initialize your pointers you should use the "address-of" operator: `&`

```cpp
const int *p1 = &x;
const int *p2 = &r;
```

You're able to set a pointer to `0` (which isn't a valid address on a PC), because that's the same thing as setting it to `NULL`.

Comment: I know that, I'm intentionally setting the pointer address to be null.  This is just for academic purposes.

Comment: *"You're able to set a pointer to 0 (which isn't a valid address on a PC), because that's the same thing as setting it to `NULL`"* C++ has no `NULL`, really; it's use is discouraged. The standard explicitly mentions that the literal `0` can be used to initialize any pointer to be a implementation defined null-pointer value. And c++11 (only) allows any `constexpr` that evaluates to `0` to be used for this as well.

Comment: *"You're able to set a pointer to 0 (which isn't a valid address on a PC), because that's the same thing as setting it to NULL."* Not the way he does it in his code, no.